# How does the family reunification visa in Switzerland work?

Tags: visa, indian-citizens, dependent-visa, switzerland

I am an Indian national, employed as a PhD student at the University of Lugano (USI), Switzerland (canton: Ticino). I have a type B residence permit. I am married and my wife is hoping to join me next year (2018). I need to know if I should apply for a family reunification visa or a dependent visa. Also, what is the procedure?

It would be helpful if you can provide some links and websites. I tried searching but I am confused as no one site provides me with complete information for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any information about a "dependent visa" on Swiss government sites; an internet search only returns discussion forums and the like, leading me to suspect that the phrase is merely an imprecise way of denoting the family reunification visa.

To apply for a family reunification visa, you should probably start at the Swiss governments page [Family reunification for third-country nationals living in Switzerland](https://www.ch.ch/en/family-reunification/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I asked this question since I couldn't find anything with a simple query based search. I need firsthand experiences from people who have dealt with such situations.

Comment: From the link above: "You are holding a residence permit (permit B)
The cantonal authorities may approve your application for family reunification, provided you meet the conditions of the Foreign Nationals Act (Art. 44).

Please contact your cantonal migration authority for more information."

That's where you need to ask. Not random strangers.